# function that reverses a string every time a vowel appears in it?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make a function that, for every occurrence of a vowel in a string, reverses said-string (and includes the vowel when it does this). The function is somewhat complex for my understanding so I'd like some help and a maybe a breakdown of it. However, **I would only like to use the operators and statements that I'm currently learning (for/while and if). If possible, I would also like to avoid using list comprehension.**

**Here's what the inputs and outputs should look like:**

an example input would be `reverse_per_vowel('aerith')`
which returns `'iraeth'`

**If we break the process of this function into steps, it should look like:**

(**a**)erith → (**a**)erith (*the first letter is a vowel, so it is reversed. However, because it is the first letter in the string, there are no visible changes.*)

(a**e**)rith → (**e**a)rith (*the second letter is also a vowel, so every letter in the string leading up to and including the vowel is reversed.*)

(ear**i**)th → (**i**rae)th (*the fourth letter is a vowel, so everything leading up to and including it is also reversed. Note how it accounts for the letters in the string that were reversed previously.*)

as you can see, the amount of times the string is reversed is cumulative and I'm not quite sure how to code for this. However, I've attempted to write a component of the function.

**What I'm trying**

```
vowellist = 'aeiouAEIOU'
sampleword = 'aerith'

indexlist = []
for i in range(len(sampleword)):
    if sampleword[i] in vowel_list:
        indexlist.append(i)
indexlist
```

output: `[0, 1, 3]`

this excerpt does not reverse any parts of the string, however it returns indexes where the string should be reversed. What I planned on doing was plugging these indexes back into the sample word somehow and using [::-1] to reverse a portion of the string. However, I don't know how I would do this nor if it would be a good idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many vowels, then the repeated reversals seem like they could be avoided, as a second reversal somewhat is an undo of the previous reversal.

And yes, you could use this algorithm:

- Build two strings. They start emtpy, and mark the second of them as the "active" one.
- Visit the input characters in reversed order: from last to first

  - As long as they are consonants add them to the currently active string
  - When it is a vowel, switch the active string to be the other one, and add the vowel there
- At the end of this process, reverse the second string and return the concatenation of the two strings:

```
VOWELS = set("aeiouAEIOU")

def reverse_per_vowel(s):
    endings = ["", ""]
    side = 1
    for c in reversed(s):
        if c in VOWELS:
            side = 1 - side  # Toggle between 0 and 1
        endings[side] += c
    return endings[0] + endings[1][::-1]
```

As this algorithm is not reversing each time it meets a vowel, but only performs one reversal at the end, it runs with linear time complexity, contrary to what you would get if you implement the described process literally, which has a worst case time complexity of O(n²).

With this complexity analysis I assume that extending a string with a character is a constant time process. If there is doubt about this, then implement it with two lists of characters, calling `append` and perform a `join` at the end of the process to get the final string:

```
VOWELS = set("aeiouAEIOU")

def reverse_per_vowel(s):
    endings = [[], []]
    side = 1
    for c in reversed(s):
        if c in VOWELS:
            side = 1 - side  # Toggle between 0 and 1
        endings[side].append(c)
    
    return "".join(endings[0] + endings[1][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to achieve this is to use recursion:

```py
vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')

def reverse_per_vowel(s):
    if not s: # empty string
        return ''
    beforelast, last = s[:-1], s[-1]
    if last in vowels:
        return last + reverse_per_vowel(beforelast)[::-1]
    return reverse_per_vowel(beforelast) + last

print(reverse_per_vowel('aerith')) # iraeth
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with simple modification of your `for` loop and some advanced slicing:

```py
vowellist = 'aeiouAEIOU'
sampleword = 'aerith'

for i in range(len(sampleword)):
    if sampleword[i] in vowellist:
        sampleword = sampleword[i::-1] + sampleword[i + 1:]

print(sampleword)
```

Every iteration if vowel appears you can just reassign string with new partly reversed.
Output:

```
iraeth
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a list makes it very easy and clean:

```
def reverse_per_vowel(word):
    result = []
    for letter in word:
        result.append(letter)
        if letter in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            result.reverse()
    return ''.join(result)
```

It's also fast. For your sample word, it was faster than all the other solutions posted so far, and for a word with 1000 letters (`'aerith' * 167`), only @trincot's second solution was a bit faster, the others were 2 to 10 times slower. Eventually of course it really loses to trincot's second solution, which at 10,000 letters was about 5 times faster and at 100,000 letters was about 46 times faster.

And here's another linear-time one, a bit faster than trincot's (tested on strings with up to a million letters). It puts the letters into a deque so it can efficiently append to the left or to the right. And it has a flag that tells whether the result is currently in reverse.

```
from collections import deque

def reverse_per_vowel(word):
    result = deque()
    reverse = False
    for letter in word:
        if not reverse:
            result.append(letter)
        else:
            result.appendleft(letter)
        if letter in 'aeiouAEIOU':
            reverse = not reverse
    if reverse:
        result.reverse()
    return ''.join(result)
```